# Pure CSS/JS Emoticons, help JS

Tags: javascript

I want to insert emoticons in my text and I use this plugin: 
http://os.alfajango.com/css-emoticons/
It works great.

My problem is I need the emoticons appears always and not only after space or at the start.

example:

:)m m:) m:)m :)

I want 4 emoticons

I bring some hours and I didn't succeed

here is the code of js

https://github.com/JangoSteve/jQuery-CSSEmoticons/blob/master/javascripts/jquery.cssemoticons.js

i think i should change something of it:

```
var specialRegex = new RegExp( '(\\' + escapeCharacters.join('|\\') + ')', 'g' );
var preMatch = '(^|[\\s\\0])';
for ( var i=twoCharacterEmoticons.length-1; i>=0; --i ){
  twoCharacterEmoticons[i] = twoCharacterEmoticons[i].replace(specialRegex,'\\$1');
  twoCharacterEmoticons[i] = new RegExp( preMatch+'(' + twoCharacterEmoticons[i] + ')', 'g' );
}
$(twoCharacterEmoticons).each(function(){                    
    container.html(container.html().replace(this,"$1<span class='" + cssClass + " spaced-emoticon'>$2</span>"));
  });
```

Comment: show where the event will be triggered?

Comment: what about the case of `(128)`

Comment: @DanielA.White im not sure what u want to say.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could change the preMatch variable to include "everything"

[This line](https://github.com/JangoSteve/jQuery-CSSEmoticons/blob/master/javascripts/jquery.cssemoticons.js#L68):

```
var preMatch = '(^|[\\s\\0])';
```

Would change to:

```
var preMatch = '(^|.)';
```

**Edit**: Answer updated with correct solution from comments.

Comment: ty for answer, I try it but it retunrs :)$2$2$2$2$2$2$2$2$2$2$2$2$2$2$2$2$2$2$2$ For this text: m:) :)m m:)m :)

Comment: Perhaps try to add the parenthesis `'(.*)'`?

Comment: Cool. I've updated the answer above just in case somebody else has the same issue ;)